# Await is a reserved word in a promise

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use await in a result of other promise but i'm receiving the message `Await is a reserved word`.

Is possible to use `await` in a promise result? I would like to avoid nested then so I'm trying to use await.

```
async function trigger(name) {
  console.log(`Trigger calls from ${name}`)
  return getConfiguration(name)
    .then(cfg => {
      let twilio = new TwilioHelper(
        cfg.twilio_account_sid,
        cfg.twilio_auth_token,
        cfg.twilio_workspace_sid
      )
      twilio
        .getWorkers()
        .list({ taskQueueName: cfg.twilio_task_queue_name, available: 'true' })
        .then(wrks => {
          console.log('number of workers available', wrks.length)
          let limit = wrks ? wrks.length : 0
          let waitingCalls = await getWaitingCalls(name, limit)
          waitingCalls.forEach(call => enqueueCall(call))
          return {}
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error', err))
}
```

Comment: as long as the function is `async` you can use `await` (you aren't using `await` in the code you posted, so what's the issue?)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write your function as follows:

```
async function trigger(name) {
    console.log(`Trigger calls from ${name}`)
    try {
        let cfg = await getConfiguration(name)
        let twilio = new TwilioHelper(
            cfg.twilio_account_sid,
            cfg.twilio_auth_token,
            cfg.twilio_workspace_sid
        )
        let wrks = await twilio.getWorkers()
            .list({ taskQueueName: cfg.twilio_task_queue_name, available: 'true' })
        console.log('number of workers available', wrks.length)
        let limit = wrks ? wrks.length : 0
        let waitingCalls = getWaitingCalls(name, limit)
        waitingCalls.forEach(call => enqueueCall(call))
        return {}   
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error', err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, however it may be the way you're trying to use the `await` keyword in the context of the promise handler. You'll need to sepcify that the handler function itself is asynchronous by using the `async` keyword on it also as shown:

```
.then(async wrks => { // Add async here
          console.log('number of workers available', wrks.length)
          let limit = wrks ? wrks.length : 0
          let waitingCalls = await getWaitingCalls(name, limit) // Add await here
          waitingCalls.forEach(call => enqueueCall(call))
          return {}
        })
```

Alternativly, it should be possible for you to express your `trigger` method solely by `async/await` in this way, if that is also something you're interested in:

```
async function trigger(name) {
    console.log(`Trigger calls from ${name}`)
    try {

        const cfg = await getConfiguration(name)

        let twilio = new TwilioHelper(
          cfg.twilio_account_sid,
          cfg.twilio_auth_token,
          cfg.twilio_workspace_sid
        )

        const workers = await twilio.getWorkers()
        const wrks = await workers.list({ 
             taskQueueName: cfg.twilio_task_queue_name, 
             available: 'true' 
        })

        console.log('number of workers available', wrks.length)
        let limit = wrks ? wrks.length : 0
        let waitingCalls = async getWaitingCalls(name, limit)
        waitingCalls.forEach(call => enqueueCall(call))
        return {}
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Error', err)
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help - all the best with your project :-)